# Float with only one decimal in c

Tags: c

I want to save all except -999.9 in another list but my code doesn't work because it saves all the numbers.

```
float nums[3]={29.34, -999.9, 63.76};
float newn[3];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
     if(nums[i]!=-999.9){
          newn[i]=nums[i];
     }
}
```

If I print `newn` it shows me: `29.34`,`-999.999999`,`63.76`

I think I know why this happens and it is because of float numbers but how can I fix
it?

Comment: Use `%.1f` to format the numbers.  By default, `%f` prints 6 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Store values x 100. e.g. `{2934, -99990, 6376}` and simply print values divided by 100, to 2 decimal places. Similar to storing monetary values in pennies as ints instead of in dollars as floats.

Comment: You're comparing a `float` value against a `double` value. Due to the different precisions: `-999.9f != -999.9`. Remember, `nums` is of type `float`, whereas `-999.9` is of type `double`. Add the suffix '`f`' to floating point literals, e.g. `-999.9f`.

Answer (score 3):

With `gcc`, using the warning flag `-Wfloat-conversion` exposes a problem here.

```
warning: conversion from ‘double’ to ‘float’ changes value from ‘2.934e+1’ to ‘2.93400002e+1f’ [-Wfloat-conversion]
    _ |         float nums[3] = { 29.34, -999.9, 63.76 };
```

The values `29.34`, `-999.9`, `63.76` are of type [`double`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant). Initializing the `nums` array with these values causes them to to be converted to the type [`float`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant). This may cause a change in [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (rounding) that cannot be reversed when this comparison

```
nums[i] != -999.9
```

[implicitly converts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) `nums[i]` to the type `double` before performing the operation.

To avoid this, use the `f` suffix on all [floating constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant) to ensure they are of type `float` (e.g., `123.456f`).

Alternatively, change the type of `nums` and `newn` to be of type `double`:

```
double nums[3] = {29.34, -999.9, 63.76};
double newn[3];
```

---

Additionally, you will need a separate variable to index `newn` with, in order to not have a gap (an uninitialized value) in the array. The final value of this variable becomes the length of the valid elements in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double nums[3] = { 29.34, -999.9, 63.76 };
    double newn[3];
    size_t n = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if (nums[i] != -999.9)
            newn[n++] = nums[i];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lf\n", newn[i]);
}
```

Comment: Or, more generally, use `-Wall`.

Comment: @jarmod AFAIK, `-Wall` does not include `-Wconversion` (`-Wfloat-conversion`), at least in recent versions of gcc.

Comment: Yes, good point. `-Wall` is an unforgiveable misnomer. Add `-Wextra` and `-Warith-conversion`.